# Error building sencha app with cmd 4.2.1 when upgrade to 5.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I've used Sencha 4.2.1 GPL and decided to purchase license.
When installed 5.1 and upgraded the cmd , now when I try to build my old apps I keep getting same errors, but the strange thing is that **"sencha app watch"** is working.

```
[INF] Compressing data with YuiJavascriptCompressor
[ERR] C2009: YUI Parse Error (missing while after do-loop body =>
          ; while ((t = t.parentNode) && 1 === t.nodeType);) -- unknown-file:149
290:25
[ERR] C2009: YUI Parse Error (Compilation produced 1 syntax errors. => null) --
unknown-file:2
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to compress input
[ERR]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown So
[ERR] urce)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 12 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Customer Projects\GIS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:255: The following error occ
urred while executing this line:
D:\Customer Projects\GIS\.sencha\app\js-impl.xml:53: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBui
ld: Failed to compress input
[ERR]
The application was last modified by an older version of Sencha Cmd (4.0.1.45)
the current is 5.1.0.26.
Please run "sencha app upgrade" to update to 5.1.0.26.
```

After upgrading I get these error :

```
   [WRN] C1019: Namespace conflicts with defined class name (Class Ext.Toolbar used
 as namespace by Ext.Toolbar.TextItem) -- D:\Customer Projects\GIS\
ext\src\toolbar\Toolbar.js:208
[INF] Compressing data with YuiJavascriptCompressor
[ERR] C2009: YUI Parse Error (missing while after do-loop body =>
          ; while ((t = t.parentNode) && 1 === t.nodeType);) -- unknown-file:146
756:25
[ERR] C2009: YUI Parse Error (Compilation produced 1 syntax errors. => null) --
unknown-file:2
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Failed to compress input
[ERR]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown So
[ERR] urce)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 10 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Customer Projects\GIS\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:266: The follow
ing error occurred while executing this line:
D:\Customer Projects\GIS\.sencha\app\js-impl.xml:71: com.sencha.exc
eptions.ExBuild: Failed to compress input
```

How can I build the app or do I need to downgrade back to cmd 4?

**EDIT**
I've uninstalled Sencha Cmd 5 and managed to build with 4... weird.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing when using YUI Compressor on the code near:

```
YUI Parse Error (missing while after do-loop body =>
; while ((t = t.parentNode) && 1 === t.nodeType);) -- unknown-file:146
```

I don't know why it gives you the filename as "unknown-file" but you should just be able to do a search in your project source code for `1 === t.nodeType` and it should narrow it down.

Comment: I don't have such string in my code (neither '1 ===' )

Comment: I think the reason you can't find the above, is because it is trying to compress the 'compiled' code.